# PrintWriter isn't writing the int values into the new file it created

Tags: java

So I'm supposed to read in a .txt file and then write a new one with the numbers backwards. For some reason only the number 0 is being printed in the new file when it should be 987654321987654321.

EDIT:
The input file reads:
123456789123456789

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Reverb
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //System.out.println("Enter the name of the file you wish to open and reverse.");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    //String s = kb.next();

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("Untitled.txt"));
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("reversamundo2.txt");

    int[] a = new int[18];
    int index = 0;

    while(inFile.hasNextInt())
        {
            a[index] = inFile.nextInt();
            index++;
        }

    for(int i = index; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        outFile.println(a[i]);
    }

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Why should it be `987654321987654321`?

Comment: If you need it all in a single line as `987654321987654321`, then you should use `outFile.print(a[i]);` instead of println. Also please share the input file data

Comment: What do you think `hasNextInt` does? What do you think is the max value that can fit in an `int`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to read character by character instead of a string and then reverse it. You can just read the String and reverse it using StringBuilder. So the code looks like:

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("Untitled.txt"));
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("reversamundo2.txt");

// Read the first String from the input file.
String line = inFile.next();

// Create a StringBuilder object for that string, reverse it and return a string.
String reverse = new StringBuilder(line).reverse().toString();

// Print the reversed string to a new file.
outFile.print(reverse);
```